# 404 response to image file call in React, uploaded w Multer/Express

Tags: reactjs, express, multer

I'm having an issue serving images from my client side that was saved to diskStorage with multer. I have my multer code below to handle the image files.

```
// image_upload.js
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, '../../../adminpanel/src/0000001');
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        const newFilename = `${uuidv4()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`;
        cb(null, newFilename);
    }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

After that code I save the filename in my db. Then I added the code below to my main express file to load the image when I call it in my react code.

```
// app.js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../adminpanel/src/0000001')));
```

When i map my (item) in my client code I load the filename and it should load the image resource.

```
// client
<img src={item.Photo} alt={item.Photo} />
```

But the images do not load. I'm getting a 404 error code on the GET image so it's as if there not there or the server can't load them on the client?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue, but I found, that something is not ok if you use express.static(...). M

Comment: I actually just fix my problem. Will edit my question with the fix and maybe it will help you as well